# Incomplete list of folders and files with Google Drive REST api v2

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am working on a Python app which gets access to Google drive. I use the [official api](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/).

Here's my code for retrieving list of root folders and files:

```
files = service.files().list(q = "'root' in parents and trashed=false",
                                         orderBy = "modifiedDate").execute()
```

The strange think is that I get only some of the folders. I just can't figure why the rest of folders are not present in the result set. I am using v2, and did not test whether the same issue is present in v3. Any ideas why this could happen ?

Comment: I see only 2 of them. Whereas the original result set should contain around 10 folders and 4 files

Comment: I've never used the raw API, just different wrappers. But in the case of those libraries, folders and files had to be shared with the email address in the oauth credentials file before they were accessible. That might be another line to investigate?

Comment: Could you please give further detail on what you mean by "sharing with the email address in the oauth credentials" ?

Comment: I'm not at a PC and it's been a while but IIRC when you activate the API on the google developer portal, you will get a credentials file to download (possibly in json format). If you open that file there will be an email address in it. You need to give access to that email address by right clicking the folder on google drive.

Comment: Aha, it's there in the guide. `client_secrets.json`. Look inside that file and there should be an email address.

Comment: ``the rest of folders`` are placed in some folders on root folder? Or those are placed on root folder?